# Freezing python-vlc with PyInstaller

Tags: python, vlc, pyinstaller

I'm trying to make a game and used python-vlc for the background music. Works on the IDLE but after freezing with *PyInstaller*, it can't seem to run.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 149, 
in __init__
  File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\xuan\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\vlc.py", line 198, in <module>
  File "site-packages\vlc.py", line 169, in find_lib
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 151, 
in __init__
__main__.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'libvlc.dll'. 
Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
[4216] Failed to execute script test
```

Please advise.Thanks

(ps. I'm very very new to coding so I might not understand the more complex stuff. Much tolerance appreciated)

Comment: As per python docs freezing support for pyinstaller is dropped. You may want to use other libraries or package product instead of freezing. See here:  http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/freezing/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. A little busy at the moment so I'll be trying some of the alternatives when I'm free and see how they go.